# CRC polynomial must include $X^0$?

Tags: computer-science, coding-theory, network

Must every polynomial include $x^0$, for example $G(x) =\dots+ x^0$?

I could not find any resource which elaborates on it.
From computer networks:

> Both the high- and low-order bits of the generator must be 1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a basic property of the GF (generator polymonial of cyclic codes, on which CRC are based), its independent coefficient cannot be zero. That's explained in every textbook, see eg [here](https://web.ntpu.edu.tw/%7Eyshan/cyclic_code.pdf), proof in page 3.